# JSpinner - Odd stepsize

Tags: java, swing, double, jspinner

I got a `JSpinner` with a step size of 0.01, but it seems, that the `getValue()` returns odd values.

As an example: its at 0.06 and if I increase that, it sometimes shows 0.06999999999999999 and not 0.07.

This kind of messes up some of my code, as I need to multiply that by 100 (0.069999999999 * 100 would be 6 and not 7!).

Any possible way to avoid that issue other than using `Math.round` for my multiplication?

```
spinnerU.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.01));
spinnerU.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        voltage = (double) spinnerU.getValue();
        lbSpannung.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", voltage));
        System.out.println("volt: " + voltage + ", 100x: "  + Math.round((voltage * 100)));
        slider.setValue((int) voltage * 100);
    }
});

output: 
volt: 0.08, 100x: 8
volt: 0.09, 100x: 9
volt: 0.09999999999999999, 100x: 10
volt: 0.1, 100x: 10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: *"(0.069999999999 * 100 would be 6 and not 7!)"* No it wouldn't. It'd be a number very close to 7.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It was. Because it would result in 6.9999 and somehow would get rounded to 6 and not 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the JSpinner.

You are using a double as model. The type double cannot store values with arbitrary precision. In fact it can't store certain values at all.

You can read more floating point in IT [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

If you want to store precise values you need a kind of integer type.